# mirth connect Database Reader automatic column mapping

Tags: mirth, mirth-connect

Please could somebody confirm the following..
I am using Mirth Connect 3.5.08232.
My Source Connector is a Database Reader.

Say, I am using a query that returns multiple rows, and return the result (via JavaScript), as documentation suggests, so that Mirth would treat each row as a separate message. I also use a couple of mappers as source transformers, and save the mapped fields in my channel map (which ends up to contain only those fields that I define in transformers)

In the destination, and specifically, in destination response transformer (or destination body, if it is a JavaScript writer), how do I access the source fields?

the only way I found by trial and error is

```
var rawMsg = connectorMessage.getRawData();
var xmlMsg = new XML(rawMsg);
logger.info(xmlMsg.some_field); // ignore the root element of rawMsg
```

Is this the right way to do this? I thought that maybe the fields that were nicely automatically detected would be put in some kind of a map, like sourceMap - but that doesn't seem to be the case, right?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Mapper steps in your transformer to extract the data and put it into a variable map (like the channel map), then you can use any of the following methods to retrieve it from a subsequent JavaScript context (including a JavaScript Writer, and your response transformer):

```
var value = channelMap.get('key');
var value = $c('key');
var value = $('key');
```

Look at the Variable Maps section of the [User Guide](https://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=217379) for more information.

So to recap, say you're selecting a column "mycolumn" with a Database Reader. The XML sent to the channel will be something like this:

```
<result>
    <mycolumn>value</mycolumn>
</result>
```

Then you can choose to extract pieces of that message into specific variables for later use. The transformer allows you to easily drag-and-drop pieces of the sample inbound message.
[image: Mapper Transformer Step]

Finally in your JavaScript Writer (or in any subsequent filter, transformer, or response transformer), just drag the value into the field you want:
[image: JavaScript Writer]

And the corresponding JavaScript code will automatically be inserted:
[image: Inserted Code]

One last note, if you are selecting a **lot** of variables and don't want to make Mapper steps for each one individually, you can use a JavaScript Step to iterate through the message and extract each column into a separate map variable:

```
for each (child in msg.children()) {
    channelMap.put(child.localName(), child.toString());
}
```

Or, you can just reference the columns directly from within the JavaScript Writer:

```
var msg = new XML(connectorMessage.getEncodedData());

var column1 = msg.column1.toString();
var column2 = msg.column2.toString();
...
```

Comment: thank you for your reply - and for your many posts on the mirth support site. in the particular case, i rather wished for all the variables to be somehow mapped automatically - in fact it IS done - it is just that the way to get them is through the serialized internal representation of the raw input message. - the reason I was wondering is that there may be lots and lots of variables - and it would be so tedious to add them one by one. but anyway - if there is no such way (or a way to create mappings for all input fields automatially, say) then I'll gladly mark your answer as THE answer.

Comment: You certainly don't have to create Mapper steps individually if you have a lot of them. Using a JavaScript step you can map everything automatically, for example. I updated my answer to note that.